# Trying to copy a file from a server/machine using Python

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I am new to Python, so I apologise if I'm asking a stupid question, but I'm struggling with this atm. I am trying to copy a folder (MachineArchiveDailyBackUp) from a machine which is using Windows CE and put it onto my Windows laptop on the C:
I get the error at the bottom.
Can anyone give me some pointers if possible please as to where I've gone wrong in the code?

Code:

```
from ftplib import FTP

ip="XX.XX.XX.XX" 
password='xxxx'
username= 'Robot'
mypath='C:\\Test\\robotbackup'

ftp=FTP(ip)
ftp.login(username,password)
files=ftp.dir('hd0a/BACKUP/MachineArchiveDailyBackUp')
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\User\Import Script.py", line 9, in <module>
ftp.login(username,password)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ftplib.py", line 414, in login
resp = self.sendcmd('PASS ' + passwd)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ftplib.py", line 281, in sendcmd
return self.getresp()
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ftplib.py", line 254, in getresp
raise error_perm(resp)
ftplib.error_perm: 501 Invalid number of arguments '0' for command 'PASS', min arg = 1, max arg = 1
```

Comment: Can you try setting `ftp.set_debuglevel(2)` and seeing what the command output looks like?

Comment: Can you try passing your login arguments as keyword arguments, like so:
`ftp.login(user=username, passwd=password)`

Comment: @zeehyt Look at the source. That will make no difference https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a885f10325eb2fc27cd50ace5614666ea688ab66/Lib/ftplib.py#L395

Comment: @flakes i see - gotcha

Comment: My best guess is that however you are setting password becomes a whitespace string, has an incorrect string encoding, or contains a newline.